# How to force Sourcetree to read svn instead of git

Tags: macos, git, svn, atlassian-sourcetree

I have to use svn for a repository, but I also maintain a git version in parallel. I don't use git-svn because the project is very large, it takes days to convert and I interrupted the process.
My question is, how to let Sourcetree manage this repo using svn instead of git, because I already have a different client for git called gitx. and I want sourcetree to manage the repo using svn instead of git.

Comment: To clarify, what is the directory set up of your git and svn repositories?

Comment: I checkout the project from svn remote with $ svn checkout, then I init an empty git repo just for me to watch the local change $ git init $ git add --all $ git commit -m "initial version after svn checkout".